# .gitignore not ignoring previously commited file in subdirectory despite *.<fileending>

Tags: git, gitignore

After having forgotten to include it in my .gitignore file, the file 'Labb1.mpf' was accidentally commited and sent upstream. Afterwards I added the line '*.mpf' into my gitignore file, but the file still showed up under 'Untracked Files' when I ran git status and became staged when I used 'git add .'. It was still in untracked files even after a commit which removed the file upstream. Labb.mpf is in a subdirectory with this structure:

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
|
└───Labb1
    │   Labb1.mpf
```

I eventually managed to make it not get included in 'git add .' by specifically writing out the full pathname in the gitignore file.

```
Labb1/Labb1.mpf
```

If I comment out this line and only run '*.mpf', the file become staged with the git add command again.

This is a solution in a way, but I don't know why and it is not a very elegant solution for a problem that may very well come up in other circumstances. Do anyone have any ideas as to how to use the asterisk command to successfully ignore, in this case, .mpf files?

I have tried with both one and two asterisks.

(Update) **Solution**:

Thanks to the tip from VonC, I got to know that any whitespace after a .gitignore declaration makes the statement fail. I had the '.mpf' statement written like this

```
*.mpf #Remove project definition file
```

were as you can see, there is a whitespace between the statement and the comment. By moving the comment to a separate line (and removing the whitespace), the statement did as intended.

Comment: Good catch, well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first, when it is working, that your file is indeed ignored by your rule:

```
git check-ignore -v -- Labb1/Labb1.mpf
```

Then, double-check the [eol (end of line)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) style of your `.gitignore`: make sure to use LF only, not CRLF.
And make sure your `*.mpf` does not have any trailing whitespace.

The [OP Simon Jansson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6801543/simon-jansson) confirms the last point:

> Any whitespace after a `.gitignore` declaration makes the statement fail.
> I had the '`.mpf`' statement written like this
>
> ```
> *.mpf #Remove project definition file
> ```
>
> where, as you can see, there is a whitespace between the statement and the comment.
> By moving the comment to a separate line (and removing the whitespace), the statement did as intended.